# Wordpress Site Stuck in maintenance mode when i moved my local site to server

Tags: wordpress

After I moved my local site to my server, my wordpress site is maintenance mode. I can access my wp-admin and even see my website but others can't see it. I tried to search for .maintenance file via ftp but it is not there. 
Please advice.

Comment: Have you change the database settings? If so, go to `Settings > Permalinks` check the `Post Name` checkbox and save the settings. Then go back and check.

Answer (score -1):

When you moved your Local site to Server you have to replace all the path where: "localhost" to your "Domain Name".

You can do this by download SQL file and open it on text editor and replace "localhost".

Comment: Thank you for replying. But i have already replaced the path of localhost to domain name.